# What JavaScript value should you assign to a variable x so that typeof x = = = x would be true?

Tags: javascript, typeof

I've tried assigning different data types such as boolean, numbers, strings, objects, nulls, etc, but keep getting false returned. Any ideas?

Comment: in addition to @Phrogz,  `typeof(typeof(x))` returns `"string"`

Comment: I think Phrogz's answer is the only one that'd work, because `typeof` returns a string

Comment: I just verified this is indeed correct. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 15):

The `typeof` operator always returns a string value. As such, your original value must be a string. The result of `typeof` for a string is `"string"`, and so:

```
x = "string"
typeof x === x // true
```